# How to get Google calendar events shared by another owner?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am new to the calendar api and have a couple of basic questions.

I want to get all of the events, on all of the calendars, that another user, tonya123456@gmail.com has shared with me.  She is the owner, not me.

"This user owns or is subscribed to 0.0 calendars" is the response when I run this code:

```
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('tonya123456@gmail.com');
if(calendar == null){
//user may not have access, auto-subscribe them.
calendar = CalendarApp.subscribeToCalendar('tonya123456@gmail.com', 
{hidden:true,selected:false});
}
Logger.log('This user owns or is subscribed to %s calendars.',
 calendar.length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I know of is listing all your own events that has a creator that you are looking for. The function below will grab your events and return an array of event ids that match the event creator. This isn't an inclusive solution, such as it doesn't have date ranges or handle paginated results and is just one simple way to approach this.

> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

```
function getEventIdsByCreator(calendarId,creator){ 
  return Calendar.Events.list(calendarId,{fields:"items/id,items/creator/email"})
          .items.filter(function(item){          
          try{if(item.creator.email === creator){return true}}
          catch(e){}
          }).map(function(item){return item.id});
}
```

You would use it like:

```
function myFunction(){
  var IDs = getEventIdsByCreator(myCalendarId,"tonya123456@gmail.com")
}
```